# Vuejs - Proper way to clone an element, and append to DOM

Tags: vue.js

I have a HTML input field to enter some information:

```
<div id="fruitForm">
    <div class="inputArea">
        <label for="fruit0">Enter Fruit Name</label>
        <input id="fruit0"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<button @click="newInputField">Add More Fruit Input Fields</button>
<button @click="submit">Submit Fruit</button>
```

And then I handle that click event:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    methods: {
        newInputField() {
            //Create another input area for users to input fruits
        },
        submit() {
            //Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

When a user selects the `Add More Fruit Input Fields` button, it should create a new input area so that the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="fruitForm">
    <div class="inputArea">
        <label for="fruit0">Enter Fruit Name</label>
        <input id="fruit0"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="inputArea">
        <label for="fruit1">Enter Fruit Name</label>
        <input id="fruit1"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<button @click="newInputField">Add More Fruit Input Fields</button>
<button @click="submit">Submit Fruit</button>
```

Now, I've been using traditional DOM manipulation methods via vanilla Javascript to accomplish this... stuff like this:

```
const inputArea = document.getElementsByClassName('inputArea');
```

And then I change the `id`'s of the input field, and then I use `appendChild` to add the new input field to the DOM.

So my question is: how *should* I be cloning this element with vuejs? I feel I'm not approaching this in the *vuejs* way. Should I be approaching this like a list and using `v-for`? Or something else?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Avoid direct DOM manipulations with Vue. You can use `data` property as a model for your template. The answer would be yes, you can and probably should use `v-for` for what you call cloning:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    inputs: [{
      id: 'fruit0',
      label: 'Enter Fruit Name',
      value: '',
    }],
  },
  methods: {
    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({
        id: `fruit${++this.counter}`,
        label: 'Enter Fruit Name',
        value: '',
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="inputArea" v-for="input in inputs" :key="input.id">
    <label :for="input.id">{{input.label}}</label>
    <input :id="input.id" v-model="input.value"></input>
  </div>
  <button @click="addInput">Add input</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I GET THIS ERROR, [Vue warn]: Property or method "addInput" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: @MattQuaine  did you declare it properly on the 'methods' object ?